# How to classify polyominoes by shape

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, symmetric-groups, hash-function, polyomino

I am trying to find a robust way to classify and distinguish [polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino). I would like to write a simple algorithm that could identify similar *free* polyominoes (under translation, rotation, reflection or glide reflection), given a set. Since I am new to this topic, I am getting a bit lost in the literature and I don't really know where to look.

I was thinking that something based on counting the length of the sides could work. For example, the following polyomino:

[image]

has one 5-length side, two 2-length sides and five 1-length sides. So we could describe it with the following notation: $\{(5,1),(2,2),(1,5)\}\,$, where the first number in parenthesis stands for the length of the side and the second one for the number of sides of that length. Then, all translations, rotations, reflections or glide reflections of this shape would result in the same description. Which is good.

However, this doesn't work in general. For example, the following two **different** polyominoes:

[image]

would result in the same description $\{(5,1), (3,1), (2,2), (1,6) \}$.

Probably, someone has already figured out a better way to do this, but, as I said, I am getting lost in the literature of the topic. Can anybody point me to the right direction?

**Update:**

Thanks for the useful suggestions in the comments. After some more research I found an interesting method, explained in the book *"Linknot: Knot Theory by Computer - S. Jablan, R. Sazdanovic"*, which works like this:

Let's imagine the path of a ray of light (bold line in figure) in a polyomino with the borders consisting of mirrors, where in every border cell we place two-sided mirrors (bolder lines) perpendicular to the internal edges in their midpoints . After a series of reflections, the ray of light will describe a shape called self-avoiding curve. If we denote a reflection in a border mirror by 0, and a reflection in an internal mirror by 1, we have 0-1 words for polyominoes, where these words are cyclically equivalent (this means, could be red starting from any sign 0 or 1 and ending in it).
For n = 1 we will have only one polyomino 0000, for n = 2 the polyomino 00010001, for n = 3 two polyominoes: 000101000101 and 000100100011, for n = 4 five of them: 0001010100010101, 0001010001100011, 001001001001, 0001001100010011, and 0001001010001011, etc.

[image]

We can translate these symbols (or binary numbers) into hexadecimal numbers and assign one number to each polyomino, in order to establish one-to-one correspondence between the numbers and polyominoes. For example, this number can be the minimum of all cyclic-equivalent symbols (e.g. to the polyomino 00010001 correspond cyclically equivalent symbols 00100010, 01000100, 10001000 and the minimum of them is 00010001 = 11 in the hexadecimal system). Hence, we have a notation for polyominoes where exactly one number corresponds to every polyomino, and vice versa.

This last part of the method is similar to what [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) was suggesting in his "dumb" method, in the comments. I don't know how the efficiency of this approach compares to the efficiency of the "dumb" one, but I think it should be faster, since we are only considering the "perimeter" of the polyomino and forgetting about the cells in the inside (this could be a problem for polyominoes with holes, but for my application I am only interested in the outer perimeter, so it's not a big deal).

However, I did not find a proof that in this notation *"exactly one number corresponds to every polyomino, and vice versa"*, even though it intuitively feels right.

**Update 2:**

To clarify, the reason why I want to label (or *encode* or *hash*, the difference is still not completely clear to me...) the polyominoes is because I have a code that simulates the evolution of a 2d system where the different states of the system can look like polyominoes (something like a [cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton)). Basically, labelling the different shapes would allow me to give at each state a unique identifier and, for example, efficiently count how many times a given state has been visited.

Comment: Graphs on a rectangular grid?

Comment: A dumb way that works goes like this: compute the bounding box of the polyomino, let's say it is $w \times h$. If $w < h$, flip the figure along a line at $45^\circ$ with $x$-axis. Divide the bounding box into $wh$ slots, place a bit $1$ or $0$ into the slot depends on whether it is covered by the polyomino. Pack all the bits into a binary integer with $wh$ bits. Do the same thing to all image of the polyomino under reflection/rotation (as long as $w \ge h$). Let $s$ be the smallest one among all the binary integers generated. The pair $(w,s)$ will uniquely identify the polyomino.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thanks, this sounds like a promising suggestion! Indeed, connecting the centres of all the cells forming a polyomino results in a grid graph. I did a bit of research but again, the literature is wide. Do you know anything or can you link me to some good resource about about the classification and encoding of grid graphs?

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed, it should work, but I think it is a bit costly. I wonder if people have already come up with some more efficient methods to do that.

Comment: @achillehui Also, why do you need to keep $w$ to identify the polyomino? Shouldn't $s$ be enough?

Comment: @Tropilio you have a vector of $wh$ bits, you need to know how to split the bits. e.g. consider the tetromino $O = $ 11-11 and $I =$ 1-1-1-1, both of them has $s = 15$.

Comment: @achillehui Yes, of course, you are right. If you have time, could you have a look at the update in the question and tell me your opinion on this method of the reflection of a ray of light? How do you think it compares to your method? Thanks!

Comment: @Tropilio The cyclic equivalence is definitely a plus, it should speed up detection of similar ominos. Whether it is more useful or not depends on how they are going to be used. For my stuff, I only need to deal with very small ominos. Whether it is dumb or smart didn't really matter. The dumb one does has one advantage. If I see a omino, I can directly write down its representation as a string of 0 and 1.

Comment: Also check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010168/algorithm-to-identify-a-unique-free-polyomino-or-polyomino-hash . Note that the border description is very similar to the ray of light (that traces the border in a more complicated way).

Comment: And here is another: https://src-bin.com/en/q/b742b8

Comment: Have you seen: https://twitter.com/PolyominoBot ?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman That's interesting, they use a "boundary word" to describe the shape of the polyomino, similar to what they do here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010168/algorithm-to-identify-a-unique-free-polyomino-or-polyomino-hash . One then still has to find a clever way to take into account reflections, but it is a nice approach!

Comment: The answer linked to by @Herman Tulleken seems to have reinvented the [shape number](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/external/57/5734.pdf), which is a standard technique in image processing and exactly solves your problem. (My linked PDF uses the 8-connected shape number, but for polyominoes a more appropriate choice would be the 4-connected version, which is exactly analogous.)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't studied the subject, so I hesitate to suggest this idea. It is geometrically intuitive, and surely simple to code in any language, but perhaps it is dreadfully inefficient.

Assign Gaussian integer coordinates to the centres of the squares in a given $n$-polyomino, compute their centroid (i.e. their arithmetic mean), and replace the coordinates with $n$ times their offsets from the centroid.

For example, the L-shape with centres $(3 + 3i, 3 + 4i, 3 + 5i, 4 + 3i)$ has centroid $\tfrac14(13 + 15i),$ so it is coded as $(-1 - 3i, -1 + i, -1 + 5i, 3 - 3i).$ (In any order, it doesn't matter.)

Let $(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n)$ and $(w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n)$ be two such lists. They represent isomorphic polyominoes if and only if $f\{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n\} = \{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\}$ for one of the $8$ functions $f(z) = \pm z, \pm iz, \pm\overline{z}, \pm i\overline{z}$ (forming a dihedral group of order $8$). So one only has to check $z_1$ against each of the $w_k$. If $f(z_1) = w_k,$ test if $f$ matches the two lists in some order. If not, try another $w_k$. If all such tests fail, the polyominoes are non-isomorphic.

(There's no need to use complex arithmetic, of course; it's just a convenient way of describing the functions $f$.)

### Example

[image: Two isomorphic tetrominoes.]

The initial lists of pairs of integer-valued square centre coordinates are:
\begin{gather*}
P : [(5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (6, 4)], \\
Q : [(-1, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, -2), (-3, -2)].
\end{gather*}
The centroids are:
\begin{gather*}
P : \left(5\tfrac14, 3\tfrac14\right), \\
Q : \left(-1\tfrac34, -1\tfrac34\right).
\end{gather*}
The scaled offsets of the square centre coordinates from the
centroids are:
\begin{gather*}
P : [(-1, -5), (-1, -1), (-1, 3), (3, 3)], \\
Q : [(3, 3), (3, -1), (-1, -1), (-5, -1)].
\end{gather*}
The algorithm compares $z_1 = (-1, -5)$ with
$w_1 = (3, 3),$ $w_2 = (3, -1),$ $w_3 = (-1, -1),$
in turn, and fails to find a match with any of them.  Next, it
compares $z_1 = (-1, -5)$ with $w_4 = (-5, -1),$ and finds that
$f(z_1) = w_4,$ where $f(x, y) = (y, x).$ (In terms of Gaussian
integers, $f(z) = i\overline{z}.$) Finally, it finds $f(z_2) = w_3,$
$f(z_3) = w_2,$ and $f(z_4) = w_1,$ and announces that $P$ and $Q$
are isomorphic.

Comment: I added some notes to my answer that relate to your answer. (They are in a way the same.)

Comment: (Bleedin' obvious afterthought.) It's just as simple to describe the functions $f$ without using any complex number notation: $f(x, y) = (\pm x, \pm y)$ or $(\pm y, \pm x)$.

Comment: @HermanTulleken I did say the coordinates were integers, and that complex arithmetic was "of course" not needed (and I've just noticed that I needn't even have mentioned it at all). Also, rational numbers (still less floating point numbers!) are not needed, because the centroids are not computed, only the integer values $\left(nx_k - \sum_{j=1}^nx_j, ny_k - \sum_{j=1}^ny_j\right)$. (I did say "compute the centroid", true, but I didn't mean that the value should actually be computed by the algorithm. It was meant as shorthand for the integer-valued formulas I've just written here.)

Comment: Ah, I did not see the centroid is multiplied by $n$ times for the offset. In any case, my main point was the techniques are basically the same.

Comment: @HermanTulleken Perhaps I've misunderstood your answer (although I did read through it, hastily, before posting my own effort), but there seems to be a significant difference. If the centroids of two $n$-polyominoes are aligned, then there are only eight possible relationships between them (rotations through multiples of $\pi/2$, with optional reflection) if they are isomorphic. On the other hand, if you normalise coordinates by making the minimum $x$-coordinate zero, you must check for translations as well as rotations and reflections. Using centroids takes care of translations automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I see I was sloppy, I will update my answer. (The idea is to make both minimum  $x$ and $y$ coordinates 0. I simply use a different offset than you.)

Comment: Thanks! While this is a very nice answer, it does not take into account my request in the Update 2: I would like to _encode_ the polyominoes, in order to give to a set of similar ones (under rotation, translation, and probably also reflection) a unique label that could tell me in which state my evolving 2d system is at a certain time.

Comment: @Tropilio Isn't it enough to have uniqueness with respect to the equivalence relation computed by my algorithm (or by another algorithm)? In particular, there is definitely no obstacle to using an equivalence relation to "count how many times a given state has been visited", which is what you said was needed. (Of course, there may be efficiency concerns, as I noted.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a unique way to identify polyominoes - essentially a name - you need to consider what the name will be used for.

If your intention is to make it easy for humans to understand what polyomino is meant, then none of the proposed schemes work well, since it will take you some time to work out which polyomino is meant by a given name. There has been other systems proposed, for example [this naming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281682/concise-naming-scheme-for-polyominoes) works like chemistry names (and suffer from the same problems).

The best way to identify a polyomino is by its image. So whatever your computer produces, simply outputting the image instead of a string name may be best. (This convention is also used in many papers on polyominoes.)

One compromise is a name like "011/110/010" (this denotes the F-pentomino shown below). You can normalize the name; that is, finding a way to choose a canonical name from the 8 possibilities, but a human can recognize all pretty easily. This is basically the same as **achille hui**s method, but you don't convert the binary. (I use this in my computer notes).

[image]

If humans are not your concern, I would recommend using a point set presentation as described below. It is the most direct, easiest to debug, and fast enough for analytics.

---

(I leave this here for others stumbling on the question.)
Before using any clever system, implement the simple algorithm first:

- Represent a polyomino as a set of coordinates, such that the minimum $x$-and $y$- coordinates are both 0. Essentially, you are subtracting the minimum corner of the hull from each point. You need the points in a consistent order, left to right for each row, and rows from bottom to top, for example.
- To compare, you do for each of the 8 orientation a point by point comparison. If all $n$ points are equal, the polyominoes are equal, otherwise, go to the next orientation. If none are equal, the polyominoes are not equal.

Already, this algorithm is not bad; you need to make less than $8n$ comparisons (in practice, way less). Also, you can get the isometries of integer points with simple (very cheap) integer arithmetic. For example, vertical reflection is $(w - x + 1, y)$.

You can get a considerable speedup by caching a few things with your polyomino that are easy to calculate. As a start, the number of cells, and the dimensions of the bounding box. If your polyominoes are big, you may store projections (how many cells in each row, how many in each column).

So you can check in order the number of cells, the bounding box dimensions, the projections, and finally a full check.

I doubt any clever scheme can do better than this. Even so, this will be a very good benchmark for speed (And correctness).

**Update:** I want to point out the answer by Calum Gilhooley is essentially the same as the one described here. He uses the centroid to normalize translation (instead of a corner of the bounding box), and keeps calculations scaled by a factor of $n$ to avoid fractions (which also is a common strategy when working rational numbers on computers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually, for my application, I will also need a way to _encode_ polyominos, or, in other words, to label them. Therefore, the two methods described above (the "dumb" one of achille hui and the "ray of light" one from the book) are more adapted for what i need to do, since they provide a way to assign a number to each different shape.

Comment: @Tropilio Ah ok. You should update your question to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should do that. Do you know about any well-known method for labelling polyominoes? I like the ideas that are coming out in the comments (there's a new one based again on encoding the perimeter of the shapes), but I wonder if the community has a "well-established" method that is efficient and easy to implement. Edit: oh, I didn't see that the user linking to the perimeter-based method is actually you!

Comment: @Tropilio :P It would be very helpful to add what you want the labeling for. If it is for lookup, then you really need hashing, not labeling. If it is for implementing some other algorithm efficiently, you probably need something else too. The reason that it is not very common in literature is that it is not usually necessary. (If your use-case is an exception that would make your question that much more interesting.)

Comment: I added an update to the question. Sorry the ignorance, but could I ask you what is the difference between hashing and labelling?

Comment: @Tropilio Labeling (as used by you, it's not an official term) is for identification and guaranteed to be unique. It's just a name. Hashing is not necessarily unique (so two polyominoes can hash to the same thing); this is used for speedup in algorithms that need lookups. I'll update my question a bit later with some notes relevant to the extra info you provided.

Comment: When you say "F-polyomino", are you talking about this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:F-pentomino_Symmetry.svg ? If yes, than I think there's a mistake in your name, and it should be $011/110/010$. Btw, what do you mean by "normalize the name"?

Comment: @Tropilio You are right, I fixed the issue and added a picture. I also clarified what I mean with normalize.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I never meant to criticize your solution; I wanted to point out the similarities. I updated that section with though to be more accurate now.

Answer (score 1):

Consider every polyomino in turn and place it against the horizontal and vertical axis. Then enumerate the lowest and highest ordinate, left to right.

For the cases below, the encodings would be $1.1/1.2/1.2/1.4/1.3$ and $1.5/1.4/1.2/2.2$.

[image]

Now group the polyominoes that are equivalent by symmetry (whichever symmetry you want), and assign the group the first description string in alphabetic order. The above two would be both labelled $1.1/1.2/1.2/1.4/1.3$.

---

Other encodings are possible,  to your taste. What matters is that every symmetric group is assigned a single "canonical" representation, unambiguously selected among all those of the group.

Comment: This only works for polyominoes that are hv-convex (each row and column needs to be contiguous), although I guess you can add another separator and add another pair. For example, the U pentomino can be $1.2/1.1/1.2$ and $1.1,3.3/1.3.$

Comment: @HermanTulleken: you are quite right, I missed that. Anyway, any representation is possible. Such as Freeman encoding of the outline squares, starting from the bottom most among the left most squares. Or encoding of all vertical runs, left-to-right and bottom-to-top, with $(x,y,l)$ coordinates.